# Mvc's ASP.NET Routing integration: Controller/Action-to-Route-Resolution

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Have a look at this route:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
   name: "FancyCustomerRoute",
   url: "fancy",
   defaults: new { controller = "SomeController", action = "Index", foo = "fancy" }
);
```

`SomeController.Index` is normally addressed as `/Some/Index?foo=something`, but for the fancy customer, it's simply `/fancy` with this route.

Through MVC's reverse route matching I expectedly get `/Some/Index?foo=mundane` for a call to `Url.Action("Index", "Some", new { foo = "mundane" })` but just `/fancy` for `Url.Action("Index", "Some", new { foo = "fancy" })`.

So far, that's great.

However, I'm looking for a way to configure the route that the `FancyCustomerRoute` route is also not taken when the `foo` parameter is *missing* rather than *different*:

`Url.Action("Index", "Some")` currently also gives me `\fancy`, which I find undesirable.

What's the best way to address this problem?

I'm using MVC5.

Comment: have you tried to use UrlParameter.Optional?

Comment: I don't think `UrlParameter.Optional` has anything to do with it. I believe it's only necessary when the value set to optional is part of the path pattern.

Comment: Maybe adding a constraint to your route definition? Try adding the constraints parameter as in : `constraints: new { foo = "fancy" },`

Comment: That does work, yes. I have to specify the value as a contraint *and* and a default though, and need to bear in mind that the contraint one is interpreted as a regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply write own `Route` class and use it as router, like this:

```
public class MyFancyRoute : Route
{
    public MyFancyRoute()
        : base("fancy", new MvcRouteHandler())
    {
        Defaults = new RouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "Some" }, 
        { "action", "Index" }, { "foo", "fancy" } };
    }

    public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, 
        RouteValueDictionary values)
    {
        return values.ContainsKey("foo")
            ? base.GetVirtualPath(requestContext, values)
            : null;
    }
}
```

And in the `RouteConfig` write this instead of yours:

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new MyFancyRoute());
```

Comment: That's really neat. I can build my own route helper that works like the default one only that all defaults are also basically "non-regex contraints": I just check whether all the given key-value-pairs are also present in the dictionary passed to `GetVirtualPath` and return null if not. - Having non-contraint "defaults" isn't really that useful anyway, especially with mvc.